# Como hacer catch del url path que se esta redireccionando en cefpython3

Tags: python

e estado varias oras intentando pillar el url path que se esta redireccionando mediante un codigo HTML con una etiqueta href en cefpython3.

Con el siguiente Handler

```
class LoadHandler(object):
    def OnLoadingStateChange(self, browser, is_loading, **_):
        if not is_loading:

            print(browser.GetUrl())

            self._OnPageComplete(browser)
```

El problema es que si la URL a la que hago la redirección mediante el href no es del tipo "http://url_que_tiene_que_existir" el browser.GetUrl() me returna una string que dice "about:blank".

La idea es que le pase un path a la etiqueta "<a>" en el codigo HTML del tipo /home no completa y pillar este path antes que la  web empieze a cargar, e estado buscando Handers que me permitan hacer esto dentro de esta doc https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython/tree/master/api pero no encontré nada que funcione de momento.

La pregunta seria, hay algun Handle o forma de hacer esto interceptar el path que se esta enviado en el navegador antes de que empieze a cargar la web ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final, lo e resuelto lo estaba planteando mal, e creado un servidor http por detrás del chromium así puedo manejar las peticiones desde haya.